# Assign custom template to DateCells in dynamically created WPF datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime, datagrid, format

I have been working on this problem for a while and I couldn't figure it out :(
I have a datagrid that dynamically filled with data. Sometimes the data is in the form of date/time.

Now, I need to do two things:

1- Delete the time and show only date (e.g.6/1/2019 12:00:00 AM ---> 6/1/2019)

2- Display datepicker on the cell upon clicking on it.

I googled for solutions and most of solutions are for static datagrid.

I tried resource method but I was not successful.

I appreciate all of your helps

Example of date column in my datagrid:

[image: Example of date column in my datagrid]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this, perhaps?

```
namespace WpfApplication {

    public class Thing
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new Thing[] {new Thing {Name = "A", Date = DateTime.Today}};
        }

        private void DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e) {
            if (e.PropertyName == "Date")
            {
                var templateColumn = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
                templateColumn.Header = "Date";
                templateColumn.CellTemplate = (DataTemplate) Resources["DateTemplate"];
                templateColumn.CellEditingTemplate = (DataTemplate) Resources["DateEditTemplate"];
                e.Column = templateColumn;
            }
        }
    }
}


<Window x:Class="WpfApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DateTemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat='d'}" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DateEditTemplate">
            <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Date, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGeneratingColumn="DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: The point is my Datagrid is dynamic meaning AutoGenerateColumns="true"

Comment: OK - edited. But I wouldn't recommend relying on AutoGenerateColumns too much - as you can see, it involves moving logic into the code behind your view which you now have to maintain and test. You've already decided to make the leap beyond AutoGenerateColumns by requiring special behaviour for at least one column.

Comment: Also, any changes to your data model (new columns, etc) are going to silently change what your user sees, even if they don't care about those changes.

Comment: It workkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkksssssssssssssssss Yessssssssssssssssssss